# Unexpected Capybara Warnings - Rails Tutorial Chapter 9 Exercise 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, railstutorial.org

I'm wrestling with Harlt's Chapter 9 exercise 9.

When I design my test for this exercise with :no_capybara set to true, like in other sections of the tutorial, the test PASSES, but I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: ignoring the provided expectation message argument (true) since it is not a string.
```

This version of the test is here:

*spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb*

```
describe "as an admin user" do 
   let(:admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
   before do  
     sign_in(admin, :no_capybara => true)
   end

   describe "should not be able to delete itself by direclty submitting request" do 
     before { delete user_path(admin) }
     specify { response.should redirect_to(users_path), 
                flash[:error].should =~ /Can't delete own admin account/i }
   end
 end
```

Note this this is how Hartl uses that method in other spaces of the tutorial, as follows:

*spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb*

```
describe 'signed in user' do 
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe 'unable to access now' do  
        before {get new_user_path}
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)}
      end
.
.
.ect...
```

However, when I do not set :no_capybara, my test fails:

```
describe "as an admin user" do 
  let(:admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
  before { sign_in(admin) } 
  .
  .
  .
Failures: 

  1) Authentication authorization as a non-admin user submitting a DELETE request to the     Users#destroy action 
     Failure/Error: before { delete user_path(user)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:68:in `admin_user'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:74:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**My two main questions are:**

1. Why is that warning occurring during that test, but not in other tests where I pass :no_capybara to the sign_in method?
2. Why is my test failing if I don't pass it no_capybara?  I've seen the other questions on stackoverflow related to this exercise, and other people's solutions don't require no_capybara.

Below is all code within my app that might be applicable. If I should include more, please let me know.

*users_controller.rb*

```
before_action :admin_user,        only: :destroy 

def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  if !current_user?(user)
    user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed.  ID: #{user.id}"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Can't delete own admin account"
  end
  redirect_to users_path
end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

*controllers/helpers/session_helper.rb*

```
def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

Comment: Having similar issues. Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think in second case rails couldn't able to find admin? method since its not present.
Thats why you are getting this error

```
NoMethodError:
undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
```

did you ran these codes

```
$ rails generate migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean 
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

As per your error, i think rails is looking for a method instead of just checking boolean value for admin.